# MRTK and Grip Press

Tags: input, controller, mrtk

I'm using MRTK 2.3.0 trying to catch a "Grip Press" event from the Mixed Reality motion controller.

I've setup the Input Action in the MRTK Toolkit in the Hierarchy of Unity. I've also assigned the action to the controller's grip button in the Controller Definitions. I'm using the following code and made sure the Grip variable is assigned to the Grip Press event. Nothing happens... I'm able to catch touchpad and joystick, menu button press, but not Grip? Why?

According to this documentation: https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/MixedRealityConfigurationGuide.html  the Grip should be a "float" as it's designed as single axis (I wonder why, since it's a button and not a trigger...). However, I'm trying to catch the event where I can... not working...

Anyone understand what the heck I'm trying to say here? (sorry, the code below also includes other events that I can catch without a hickup).

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input;
 using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit;

 public class TestInput : MonoBehaviour, IMixedRealityBaseInputHandler, 
 IMixedRealityInputHandler<Vector2>, IMixedRealityInputHandler
 {
 public MixedRealityInputAction Trigger, Grip, Scroll, Swipe, Joystick, DPad, TouchPadClicked, TouchPadTouched, MenuPressed;
 public MixedRealityInputAction DPadUp, DPadDown, DPadLeft, DPadRight, JoystickUp, JoystickDown, JoystickLeft, JoystickRight;
 private bool TouchpadPressed, MenuButtonPressed, GrabPressed, TouchDialogPadPressed, TouchpadClicked, Thouchpadtouched,
           ThumbstickActive, ThumbstickPressed, VRManipulationStarted, ScrubStarted, PlayPause = false;


private void OnEnable()
{
    IMixedRealityInputSystem inputSystem;
    if (MixedRealityServiceRegistry.TryGetService<IMixedRealityInputSystem>(out inputSystem))
    {
        inputSystem?.RegisterHandler<IMixedRealityBaseInputHandler>(this);
        inputSystem?.RegisterHandler<IMixedRealityInputHandler<Vector2>>(this);
        inputSystem?.RegisterHandler<IMixedRealityInputHandler>(this);
        inputSystem?.RegisterHandler<IMixedRealityInputHandler<float>>(this);
    }
}

private void OnDisable()
{
    IMixedRealityInputSystem inputSystem;
    if (MixedRealityServiceRegistry.TryGetService<IMixedRealityInputSystem>(out inputSystem))
    {
        inputSystem?.UnregisterHandler<IMixedRealityBaseInputHandler>(this);
        inputSystem?.UnregisterHandler<IMixedRealityInputHandler<Vector2>>(this);
        inputSystem?.UnregisterHandler<IMixedRealityInputHandler>(this);
        inputSystem?.UnregisterHandler<IMixedRealityInputHandler<float>>(this);
    }
}

public void OnInputChanged(InputEventData<Vector2> ed)
{
    Debug.Log("InputChanged");
    if (ed.MixedRealityInputAction == DPad)
    {
        Debug.Log("Touched Touchpad at:" + ed.InputData.x.ToString() + "," + ed.InputData.y.ToString());
    }
    if (ed.MixedRealityInputAction == Joystick)
    {
        Debug.Log("Touched Joystick at:" + ed.InputData.x.ToString() + "," + ed.InputData.y.ToString());
    }
}

public void OnInputChanged(InputEventData ed)
{
    if (ed.MixedRealityInputAction == MenuPressed)
    {
        Debug.Log("Menu button pressed");
        //ActionText.text = "Grab pressed";
    }

 }

 public void OnInputChanged(InputEventData<float> ed)
 {
    Debug.Log("Float Changed");
    if (ed.MixedRealityInputAction == Grip)
        Debug.Log("Grab Pressed");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok... I got this..... It's a BUG in MRTK.

I have 18 actions defined (when you have DPad left, up, down etc it goes by fast!).

When I try to assign my MixedRealityInputAction to an InputAction in the Inspector, when I try to select GrabPressed (which is the 18th action), I get

```
 IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
 Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.Editor.InputActionPropertyDrawer.OnGUI
```

Therefore the action does not work....

I tried to use another InputAction instead and assign it to the grab button (I used Select in this case) and it works like a charm....

Beware....

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Input.GetAxisRaw(ControllerMappingLibrary.AXIS_11) > 0 || Input.GetAxisRaw(ControllerMappingLibrary.AXIS_12) > 0;
```

AXIS_11 is grip press for the left controller while 12 is for the right controller